# How to return mysqli result object from a function in a class?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli, crud

So.. I am practicing my PHP by writing a database object with CRUD operations.. However, I am having trouble returning a result object from the database object.

This is the relevant "select_where" function which lives inside the db Class and takes one parameter specifying the table name:

```
       function select_where(array $values, $table, $what = "*")
    {
        $where_stmt = '';

        if(count($values)>0)
        {
            $fields = array_keys($values);
            $vals   = array_values($values);

            if ($what != "*")
            {
                if(is_array($what)===TRUE)
                {
                    $what = implode($what, ',');
                }
                else //assume string! -- needs better error handling!
                {
                //Don;t do  anything for now
                }

            }

            $where_stmt = "WHERE ";

            for( $i=0 ; $i<count($fields) ; $i++)
            {
                $where_stmt .= "$field[$i] = '$vals[$i]' AND ";

            }

            $where_stmt .= "$field[$i] = '$vals[$i]'";


        }//else: array is an empty one, meaning SELECT ALL;


        $query = "SELECT $what FROM `$table` $where_stmt;";
        ;

        if($result = $this->mysqli_conn->query($query))
        {
            echo "RESULT:<br />";
            print_r($result);
            return $result;

        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

The print_r function prints the attributes of the result object with no issues.. BUT when I call my function, it does not.. As so:

```
    $db = new db();

    $result = $db->select_all('codes');

    print_r($result);
```

print_r does not print anything...

I am 100% sure that this has to do with my lack of understanding of how PHP OOP works; while I look for answers elsewhere, any suggestions or solutions are highly appreciated!

---

LOOKS LIKE I've Found the answer:

ROOKIE MISTAKE!

In my code, I used the helper function
     $result = $db->select_all('codes');

which actually looked like this:

```
function select_all($table, $what="*" )
    {
        $empty_array = array();
        $this->select_where($empty_array, $table, $what);

    }
```

But as one can see, there was no return from THIS function! So now:

```
function select_all($table, $what="*" )
    {
        $empty_array = array();
        return $this->select_where($empty_array, $table, $what);

    }
```

is the solution!

Thank you again

Comment: try return $result->fetchAll();

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump($result);`? you should hopefully see a mysqli result object

Comment: @AndreiAndrei I've tried that and still no return !

Comment: you should edit your question to add the complete code of the function

Comment: @Asenar .. I've included the whole code, but the answer has been found.. thanks! (Since I am new, I cannot answer the question for 8 hours, so I've edited it)

Comment: good job so, and welcome here :)

Comment: @asenar Thank you! Looking forward to contributing..